# Onclick feature on the action button to slide the slidebar

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Below application has sidebar open by default. Is there a way to make it close by default and slide when the user clicks on "Release" button.
So when the user clicks again on teh button, the side bar should slide inside and this is on and off type. Can we achieve this

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      
      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      ),
      box(actionButton("release", "Release"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A version using the `onclick` event:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      ),
      box(actionButton("release", "Release", onclick = "$('body').toggleClass('sidebar-collapse');"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```